# Spring Boot + DynamoDBTypeConverter dependancy injection

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get DI working with a sample DynamoDBTypeConverter I'm playing around with and having no luck at all :( My service is always null and throws an error as a result in my jUnit test.
Here's my converter:

```
@Component
public class ArmTypeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Arm> {
    @Autowired
     private ArmRepository armRepository;

    @Override
    public String convert(Arm Arm) {        
        return arm.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Arm unconvert(String id) {
        return armRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

My application main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan 
@EnableSpringConfigured 
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ArmApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ArmApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() throws Throwable {
        InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
        return loadTimeWeaver;
    }
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class ArmServiceImpl implements ArmService {
    @Autowired
    private ArmRepository armRepository;

    @Override
    public Arm create(String length, Set<Register> registers) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Arm arm = new Arm();
        arm.setLength("85cm");

        return armRepository.save(arm);
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ArmServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    private ArmService armService;

    @Autowired
    private TorsoService torsoService;  

    private Arm arm;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        arm = armService.create("85cm", null);
        torsoService.create("150cm", arm);
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        // do nothing for now...
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("admin@somewhere.com")
    public void getArmTest() {
        Arm c = armService.getArm(arm.getId());

        assertThat(c).isNotNull();
        assertThat(c.getId()).isEqualTo(arm.getId());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the service and junit code.

Comment: I updated the OP

Comment: Can we have the logs as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't have load time weaving configured properly